# My question was closed for an (in my opinion) incorrect reason

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request

[My question](https://superuser.com/questions/723810/why-is-more-ram-needed-if-youre-running-on-a-vm) was closed a while ago. I forgot to make this post until now, sorry it's so late!

Anyway, it was being closed for being **primarily opinion-based**. However, this was not the case.

The answer has to do with hardware and is not *Is X better than Y?*. It was a *Why does X happen with Y?* question, something with a definite (or multiple definite) answer(s).

Can someone explain to me the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's opinion-based, because nobody could really know why Microsoft came up with those requirements, except they themselves.

I would also say that none of the existing answers are convincing with their assumptions. I personally would have assumed a different reason for the requirement altogether. Which just furthers the point that it is opinion-based.